# iOS 15 Mail app only displays <img> alt text, can't load remote images

Tags: html, ios, email, html-email, email-client

Since iOS15, Apple's native Mail app shows our organization's email images as alt text instead of the image. We build the email in HTML, and use our FTP server to host images, and link them in the body of the email. Our emails work fine in ALL other clients, but for some reason Mail blocks them, and does not present an option to download remote images. Other emails come across fine and images are shown.

I've tried disabling the new privacy features under Settings>Mail>Privacy Protection, and it doesn't fix anything.

Is there some reason this is happening specifically with our emails? I've attached a sample of the code for our header image in our emails. Appreciate any insight here.

```
<table bgcolor="#eeeeee" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" title="Header Section">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
        
        <!-- LAYOUT TABLE -->

        <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="700" class="device-width">
          <tr>
            <td>
                
                <img src="http://mayacamainternal.com/graphics/clubdues2020/clubduesheader1.jpg" alt="Mayacama Header Image" style="display: block; width: 100%;" width="700" />


            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>      

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Have you tried linking your image using `https`?

Comment: @HTeuMeuLeu I have not, but I have suspected that might be the reason, but I haven't been able to find anything saying that Apple is blocking non HTTPS links.

Comment: @HTeuMeuLeu I verified that HTTPS made no difference. I am thinking apple is blocking everything from hostmonster?